# How could I write this short function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, authentication

So I have this code written using jquery, of which is a familiar language for me. However, I have not been able to successfully convert this to a javascript, not using jquery. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
// Toggle Function
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  // Switches the Icon
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-pencil');
  // Switches the forms  
  $('.form').animate({
    height: "toggle",
    'padding-top': 'toggle',
    'padding-bottom': 'toggle',
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
});
```

This code switched the icons and forms for my login page.

Any tips would be very helpful, thanks for everything!

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. I don't know how people get confused about that but it's really common. What you're asking is how you can perform the various services that the jQuery library supports by using either browser APIs or, possibly, another library. Some services are easy to replicate with browser APIs, but some (like `.animate()`) are considerably less easy.

Comment: @Pointy sorry for the misunderstanding, but this works perfectly with a browser. My problem is that when used in a chrome extension I can't toggle back and forth. It could be that its jquery (I know Jquery is Javascript) or I could be completely wrong but I am working on figuring something out right now. Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Well, as I said things like the event handler binding are pretty easily done with the browser `.addEventListener()` DOM API, but the animation stuff is pretty much all jQuery; it's a fairly complicated mechanism involving timers and queuing logic.

Comment: @Pointy `jQuery` not `Javascript`! `jQuery` is a cross platform `JavaScript` library! When you say `jQuery is JavaScript` It will confuse people! They thought both are same. What OP said, is brightly clear! want to convert `jQuery` code to native `Javascript` code.

Comment: @Mr.x jQuery is written in JavaScript. Every "jQuery program" is in fact a JavaScript program. And the DOM APIs are *not* JavaScript. They're *available* to JavaScript in browser environments, but they are not part of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough conversion into native JavaScript.  You'll need to provide the CSS ".show" definition and possibly define some CSS animations there to get whatever animation you want.

```js
const toggleElement = document.querySelector('.toggle');

toggleElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const icons = this.querySelectorAll('i');
    icons.forEach(iconElement => iconElement.classList.toggle('fa-pencil'));

    const form = document.querySelector('.form');
    form.classList.toggle('show');
}, false);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!